# the compact Hausdorff $\beta X$

Tags: general-topology, compactness, proof-explanation

The bellow example show that the compact Hausdorff $\beta X$ does not have  non-trivial subsequence:

Assume $R=(\mathcal{U}_n)_n$ is a sequence of distinct ultrafilters on some set $X$. Since every Hausdorff space has an infinite discrete subspace, there is a subsequence $R=(\mathcal{V}_n)_n$ of $R=(\mathcal{U}_n)_n$ such that $\{\mathcal{V}_n|n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a discrete subspace of $\beta X$. In particular, there is a sequence $(A_n)_n$ of sets with $A_n \in \mathcal{V}_m$ if and only if $m =n$. If we let $B_n=A_n - (A_0 \cup...\cup A_{n−1})$, then the sequence $(B_n)_n$ is pairwise disjoint and $B_n \in \mathcal{V}_m$  iff $m=n$. If we let $B =\cup_n B_{2n}$, then $B \in \mathcal{V}_m$ if and only if $m$ is even. In other words, if $B =\{ \mathcal{V} \in βX|B \in \mathcal{V}\}$, then $B$ is a clopen set with $\mathcal{V}_m \in B$ iff $m$ is even. Therefore, we conclude that the sequence $(\mathcal{V}_m)_m$ cannot converge to any point, so the sequence $(\mathcal{U}_n)_n$ cannot converge to any point either.

> I would like to know that:
>
> (1) :What does it mean "sequence of **distinct** ultrafilters on some set $X$"?I mean, is it possible to define different ultrafilters on some set $X$?
>
> (2) Why "$B_n \in \mathcal{V}_m$  iff $m=n$"? And " $B =\cup_n B_{2n}$, then $B \in \mathcal{V}_m$ if and only if $m$ is even "?
>
> (3)$B$ is a clopen set with $\mathcal{V}_m \in B$ iff $m$ is even

Comment: As to (1), every infinite set $X$ has $2^{2^{|X|}}$ many different (free) ultrafilters defined on it.